# Stemming and stop words removal in Lucene 4.7 for Arabic

Tags: lucene, stop-words, stemming

Could please help me how I can use Lucene's stemmer and stop words removal for Arabic language?

Also, I want to know both:

- USe my own stop words list.
- Use Lucene list.

Thank you in advance.

Update:

I wrote this code:

```
    DocumentReader documentReader = new DocumentReader(filePath);
    ArrayList<String> stopWordsList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(documentReader.readFile().split("\\s+")));
    CharArraySet stopwords = new CharArraySet(Version.LUCENE_47, stopWordsList, true);
    ArabicAnalyzer arabicAnalyzer = new ArabicAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47, stopwords);
    TokenStream tokenStream = arabicAnalyzer.tokenStream("?", TextProcessor.text);
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, tokenStream, stopwords);
    TextProcessor.text = tokenStream.reflectAsString(true);
```

I imported the following:

```
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.ar.ArabicAnalyzer;
    import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilter;
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet;
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.ar.ArabicStemmer;
```

I used these jars:

```
    ArabicAnalyzer.jar
    lucene-analyzers-common-4.7.0.jar
    lucene-core-4.7.0.jar
```

But I wasn't able to test the output as I am not getting the string?
So how can I get the text after it the stop words were removed?

Note, what I should put in the first parameter of
        arabicAnalyzer.tokenStream("?", TextProcessor.text);

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Arabic stemmer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ar/ArabicStemmer.html) is in `lucene-analyzers-common` package. If you are using maven, simply add the [relevant dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common).

To use custom stopword list, simply use the relevant constructor of [`StandardAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) (which has `stopWords` parameter), or use constructor without stopwords param for the Lucene-default set. If you are using a different analyzer, you need to tell us which to advise you.

Comment: I am new to Lucene and my aim to give the stemmer a text then it should stem it and I couldn't find a way to do that. Thus, kindly could you provide me by an example of how to use it?

Comment: [Here](http://www-pagines.fib.upc.es/~ri/session2-eng.html) is some basic explanation, although not for Arabic stemmer. But you will get the idea.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful, but I still not be able to run the code successfully. I had updated my question, please help me to come over the problem. @mindas

Comment: You can not use different Lucene versions (4.6.0 and 4.7.0) in the same project.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, I had modified the code and get rid from the errors, please see the original post for the update.